# Is asking for a quote on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm looking for an C.S Lewis quote (where he talks about trees an dryades) which I can citate analogous. Is a question like this on topic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. That's more of a literature question really. In fact most SE sites don't handle those sort of questions even when they are topical. The [Movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) site does, but I'm not sure if [Liturature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) does or not, you could ask on their meta I guess.

We cover a lot of questions about C.S. Lewis's works because he was an influential thinker and writer (if a bit sketchy as a theologian) and so we can cover his theology and it's bearing on modern Christian traditions, but quote requests from his extensive fiction works (even if they do have Christian themes) is not really in our wheel house because they are about his writings not Christianity.

Comment: I only -1'ed because I don't want people to get the wrong idea about not being able to ask about fiction on the site.

Comment: @PeterTurner Fiction itself _is_ off topic here, the history and theology of influential thinkers  is on topic  and  if they happened to by fiction writers their works will inevitably play into that — but the things that can be asked about are their theology in relation to Christianity, not their fiction writings as works of literature.

Comment: @PeterTurner It might be also worth mentioning that we don't even really appreciate "name that quote" when the quotes are in the Bible itself. "Give me the reference for this thing I'm thinking of" just  isn't a good question pattern even if the fiction thing didn't factor in at all.

Answer (score 0):

Caleb is right, we don't service Bible ID questions and we don't service Random Christian author questions,

But, I do disagree with him when he writes that fictional works with Christian themes are off-topic.  They're off-topic if the theme is tangential to his theology, but since from a certain point of view, which Chesterton (and I think Lewis) held, this is impossible to hold the point of view that anything is truly unrelated from theology, you would have to work to ask a question that is unrelated from Christianity.

I had pretty good success asking about [Chesterton here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18375/in-the-ball-and-the-cross-where-did-mcian-go-wrong)

I don't know how you could phrase *this* question (I'm not even sure what the question is) to fit on the site.

- What did Lewis say about dryads in relation to trees?

is a bit too broad

- Did Lewis believe in dryads?

is a leading question that might be topical, maybe too specific.

I think fishing with:

- How did C.S. Lewis reconcile a belief in fairyland with Christianity?

and then note in the question that you'd like to know what he thought about different sorts of fairies, dryads being an important one, you may wind up getting what you want out of answers.

Comment: Lewis philosophized about the question of what a tree is. He explained this in two opposing points of view: a tree is only interconnected cells or a tree is inhabited by a dryad. He came to the conclusion that in this case, the Dryad comes closer to the truth. The literal quote / the source  is what I'm looking for.